# How many parameters in a Conv2d Layer?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution, convolutional-neural-network

I was following andrew-ng coursera course on deep learning and there's a question that has been asked there which I couldn't figure out the answer for?

Suppose your input is a 300 by 300 color (RGB) image, and you use a convolutional layer with 100 filters that are each 5x5. How many parameters does this hidden layer have (including the bias parameters)?

1. 2501
2. 2600
3. 7500
4. 7600

Comment: I was asked this recently as an interview question (different parameters for the conv layer, but essentially the same question).  Study up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right answer is the fourth.

From [this](https://medium.com/@iamvarman/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-parameters-in-the-cnn-5bd55364d7ca), the formula to calculate the number of parameters in a convolutional layer is `(n*m*l+1)*k` with `n = m = 5`, `k = 100`, `l = 3` and `+1` for the bias.

Answer (score 3):

As we have a RGB Image so our filter changes from 2D to 3D, whose dimension will be 5 * 5 * (no of channels from previous layer) = 5 * 5 * 3 = 75

Now we have 100 such filters, so total parameters increases to = 75 * 100 = 7500

Each filter has a constant bias associated with it, hence this introduces 100 biases for each filter or l00 more features

Total feature required = 5 * 5 * 3 * 100 + 100 = 7600

Answer (score 3):

Based on the equation in the course:

[image]

- Weights `5 * 5 * 3 * 100 = 7500`
- Bias `100`

So total would be 7600.